# Oracle' s Jdbc tutorial example for binding CLOB

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, instantiation

I am trying to understand how I can pass a `CLOB` to a database using `JDBC`. I am using `Oracle 11g` and `Oracle's JDBC Driver 12.1.0.1`.

I was looking through Oracle's Jdbc tutorial and [I found this sample code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html). It reads the contents of a file and writes to a Clob  instance , which it then writes to the database using `INSERT` . For sake of readability , I am posting only relevant portions of the code:

```
        Clob myClob = this.con.createClob();
        Writer clobWriter = myClob.setCharacterStream(1);
        String str = this.readFile(fileName, clobWriter);
        System.out.println("Wrote the following: " +
            clobWriter.toString());

        if (this.settings.dbms.equals("mysql")) 
        {
            System.out.println("MySQL, setting String in Clob " + "object with setString method");
            myClob.setString(1, str);
        }

        System.out.println("Length of Clob: " + myClob.length());

        String sql = "INSERT INTO COFFEE_DESCRIPTIONS " + "VALUES(?,?)";

        pstmt = this.con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, coffeeName);
        pstmt.setClob(2, myClob);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Here is the code for the `readFile` method:

```
    private String readFile(String fileName, Writer writerArg) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String nextLine = "";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println("Writing: " + nextLine);
        writerArg.write(nextLine);
        sb.append(nextLine);
    }

    // Convert the content into to a string
    String clobData = sb.toString();

    // Return the data.
    return clobData;
}
```

I modified the above sample code to pass a CLOB to a PL/SQL procedure.

```
 public String handleEmployeeReview(int empId , String fileName) throws IOException
 {
     Connection conn = null;
     CallableStatement callStmt = null;
     String reviewContent = null;

     try 
     {
         // Register the Oracle Jdbc driver 
         // Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER_ORACLE);

         // Create a database connection
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PWD);

         // Create a query string
         String callProc = " { call HR.EMP_PKG.handle_employee_review ( ? , ? , ? ) } ";

         // Create a Callable Statement
         callStmt = conn.prepareCall(callProc);

         // Bind values to the first IN parameter
         callStmt.setInt(1, empId);


         // Create CLOB and use ClobWriter
         Clob reviewFileClob = conn.createClob();
         Writer clobWriter = reviewFileClob.setCharacterStream(1);
         String  reviewStr = this.readFile(fileName , clobWriter);
         callStmt.setClob(2, reviewFileClob);


         // Register OUT parameter
         callStmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

         // Execute the callable statement
         callStmt.execute();

         // Retreive the OUT parameters
         reviewContent = callStmt.getString(3);
         System.out.println("Employee with id : "+ empId + " has annual review : " + reviewContent);
     }
```

Here is the PL/SQL procedure:

```
  -- PURPOSE: Takes Clob and returns its contents
  -- Example of: PROCEDURE that takes a Clob as IN parameter
  PROCEDURE handle_employee_review(empId IN VARCHAR2 , empReviewDoc IN CLOB , reviewContent OUT VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    reviewContent := empReviewDoc || ' THIS IS COMING FROM THE DATABASE';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error!');
  END handle_employee_review;
```

**On running my adapted code I don't see anything being sent to the database. How do i get this code to work ? It seems like this line `writerArg.write(nextLine);` in the `readFile` method is not working as expected ?** Here is the output for my code:

```
Employee with id : 101 has annual review :  THIS IS COMING FROM THE DATABASE
```

Here is the snapshot of my debugger. I do see data being written to the CLOB's Writer

[image]

**If you notice in the above o/p , PL/SQL code finds nothing in the CLOB.**

On the other hand if I pass contents to the CLOB in the following way ( which the tutorial's example also uses but just for MYSQL databases). ***I have also passed file content to a CLOB just with the `setString` method without using the Clob's Writer instance. It works just fine.***

```
         Clob reviewFileClob = conn.createClob();
         String  reviewStr = this.readFile(fileName , clobWriter);
         reviewFileClob.setString(1, reviewStr);
         callStmt.setClob(2, reviewFileClob);
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Employee with id : 101 has annual review : Employee Exceeds Expectations THIS IS COMING FROM THE DATABASE
```

**NOTE:** I have stripped down the original code (removed try catch blocks , database / file resource cleanup ) to post only the relevant code. The post was getting a little too lengthy.